# How to compare two columns in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

```
Df1:

Id   Name
 1     A
 2     B
 3     B
 3     A
 2     A
 6     B
```

I need to create a new column Based on Id and Name Column. If same  Id is present Name Column Values. For Example Id 3,2 present for both A and B.

Df1:

```
Id   Name  New_Col
 1     A    Unique
 2     B    Common
 3     B    Common
 3     A    Common
 2     A    Common
 6     B    Unique
```

Comment: Do you only need to check if the id is unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `transform` + `nunique`

```
df'[out'] = np.where( df.groupby('Id')['Name'].transform('nunique').eq(1), 'Unique', 'Common')

Out[519]: 
0    Unique
1    common
2    common
3    common
4    common
5    Unique
Name: Name, dtype: object
```